# Firebase CLI Typescript error TS2345 thrown on code that previously compiled

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase

Good evening,

I recently updated the firebase CLI for cloud functions, and when I try to deploy my old index.ts file, I get a TS2345 error:

```
src/index.ts:364:13 - error TS2345: Argument of type '(req: Request, res: Response<any>) => Response<any> | Promise<void | Response<any>>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(req: Request, resp: Response<any>) => void | Promise<void>'.
  Type 'Response<any> | Promise<void | Response<any>>' is not assignable to type 'void | Promise<void>'.
    Type 'Response<any>' is not assignable to type 'void | Promise<void>'.
      Type 'Response<any>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<void>'.

364  .onRequest((req, res) => {
```

my function that is trowing this error looks like this:

```
exports.https_rec = functions.https
    .onRequest((req, res) => {
        if (req.method === 'PUT') {
            console.log("HTTPS Attempted Connection");
            return res.status(403).send('Forbidden!');
        }
        else{
           //Do Stuff
           return res.status(200).send("ok");
        }
    });
```

Everything was working and uploading fine, but after I updated the CLI, I now get this TS2345 error on code that previously compiled. I found a sample function from Firebase (from a few years ago) where the structure is the same as how I have presented it, which tells me something must have changed recently.

https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/quickstarts/time-server/functions/index.js#L39

Other specs:
Windows 10
NPM Version 14.5.0
Firebase-tools version 8.6.0

Any thoughts or recommendations? Is there an easy code change to make, or should I revert back to an older version of the CLI or tslint?

Thank you for your time in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They changed the return type of https triggers recently.

You shouldn't "return" anything as a response.

Just delete `return` and you're good to go.

Example:

```
exports.https_rec = functions.https
.onRequest((req, res) => {
    if (req.method === 'PUT') {
        console.log("HTTPS Attempted Connection");
        return res.status(403).send('Forbidden!');
    }
    else{
       //Do Stuff
       res.status(200).send("ok");
    }
});
```